# Unable to use primary WiFi network. Guest WiFi network is fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I just changed my modem yesterday. I use 2 TP-Link Archer C6 routers. One as router and the other as repeater.

I am able to connect to my primary WiFi as well as my guest WiFi.

My internet is working through the guest network.

But my internet is not working through primary network.

What shall I check or change?

I have DHCP enabled in one Archer C6 router and in the other Archer C6 that I use as a repeater, I have turned DHCP off.

And I have disabled IPv6. As I dont need it in my home.

Comment: “I just changed my modem yesterday.” You mention modem, but then you mention routers. Did you change your modem as well as your routers? Or are you no longer using your modem as a router?

Comment: We will need more information to diagnose the reason your modem isn’t functioning properly